# Passing different parameters to each mapper

Tags: java, hadoop

I have a job that uses multiple mappers and one reducer. The mappers are almost identical, except they differ in the value of a `String` that they use to produce the result.

Currently I have several classes, one for each value of the `String` I mentioned — it feels like there should be a better way, that doesn't require so much code duplication. Is there a way to pass these `String` values as parameters to the mappers?

My job looks like this:

```
Input File A  ---->  Mapper A using
                       String "Foo"  ----+
                                         |--->  Reducer
                     Mapper B using  ----+
Input File B  ---->    String "Bar"
```

I want to turn it into something like this:

```
Input File A  ---->  GenericMapper parameterized
                               with String "Foo" ----+
                                                     |--->  Reducer
                     GenericMapper parameterized ----+ 
Input File B  ---->            with String "Bar"
```

**Edit:** Here are two simplified mapper class that I currently have. They accurately represent my actual situation.

```
class MapperA extends Mapper<Text, Text, Text, Text> {
    public void map(Text key, Text value, Context context) {
        context.write(key, new Text(value.toString() + "Foo"));
    }
}

class MapperB extends Mapper<Text, Text, Text, Text> {
    public void map(Text key, Text value, Context context) {
        context.write(key, new Text(value.toString() + "Bar"));
    }
}
```

**Edit:** What string each mapper should use depends only on which file the data comes from. There is no way to differentiate between the files, except through the file name.

Comment: some actual Mapper code woudl be great i think. Or at least your current Mapper structure

Comment: @maffelbaffel I added some code.

Comment: How different is Mapper A from B other than the additional string? Are you using multiple inputs? How many files do you have? 

From the driver code, you can pass the "string" associated to each file name and from the map() you can get the filename being currently processed and append the necessary key.

I believe I have not got the question fully. Am I missing something.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you use file input formats, you can get you current input file name in the mapper like this:

```
if (context.getInputSplit() instanceof FileSplit) {
    FileSplit fileSplit = (FileSplit) context.getInputSplit();
    Path inputPath = fileSplit.getPath();
    String fileId = ... //parse inputPath into a file id
    ...
}
```

You can parse inputPath however you want, e.g. use file name only or partition id only, etc to generate a unique id identifying the input file.
For example:

```
/some/path/A -> A
/some/path/B -> B
```

Configure your properties for each possible file "id" in your driver:

```
conf.set("my.property.A", "foo");
conf.set("my.property.B", "bar");
```

In the mapper compute file "id" as stated above and get the value:

```
conf.get("my.property." + fileId);
```

Comment: I believe this is the same as what I commented :)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you would use if sentence inside your mapper for choose between strings. What depends the use of one string or another?

Or maybe use Abstract Mapper class.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this ?

```
abstract class AbstractMapper extends Mapper<Text, Text, Text, Text> {
    protected String text;
    public void map(Text key, Text value, Context context) {
        context.write(key, new Text(value.toString() + text));
    }
}
class MapperImpl1 extends AbstractMapper{
    @Override
    public void map(Text key, Text value, Context context) {
        text = "foo";
        super.map();
    }
}
class MapperImpl2 extends AbstractMapper{
        @Override
        public void map(Text key, Text value, Context context) {
            text = "bar";
            super.map();
        }
    }
```

Comment: If I am not mistaken, this approach would not help to reduce the code into an unique mapper clas, since it would still require a custom implementation for each mapper type.