# Pass a parameter to the same mapper to make it behave differently for different files

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, bigdata

I am trying to reuse the same mapper for different input files with different configurations. Since I am reusing the mapper, I want to pass some context info to mapper regarding which key/file it is currently running for.

All mappers follow almost same logic, with the mapper output being determined by rules. To add a new file to be mapped, we should just update this configuration and a new mapper will be added. Below is a sample rule file:

```
[
{
    "key":"company1",
    "fields":["name", "age", "salary", "department", "state"],
    "mapperFilePath":"/from-dw/company1Employees.tsv",
    "rulesFilePath":"configuration/attribution/company1Rules.js"
},
{
    "key":"company2",
    "fields":["firstName", "LastName", "department", "salary", "country"],
    "mapperFilePath":"/from-dw/company2Employees.tsv",
    "rulesFilePath":"configuration/attribution/company2Rules.js"
},
]
```

I wrote a generic mapper that can read the config and run the appropriate rules file to compute mapper outputs. It can read the config only if "key" is available.

```
public class GenericMapper extends Mapper<K,V,KO,VO> {
    @Override
    protected void setupMap(Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        super.setupMap(context);
        // RECEIVE KEY HERE 
    }

    @Override
    public void map(LongWritable positionInFile, Text line, Context context)
    {
        // processing here depends on the key
    }
}
```

The driver class reads the config file and create as many mappers as needed. I need a way to pass the "key" parameter from here to the mapper.

```
public class Driver extends Configured implements Tool {

    @Override
    protected boolean setupJob(Job job) throws Exception {
        Configuration conf = job.getConfiguration();
        Map<String, Config> companyConfigMap = configsHolder.getConfigMap();
        for (Map.Entry<String, Config> eachEntry : companyConfigMap.entrySet()) {
            String key = eachEntry.getKey();
            String filePath = eachEntry.getValue().getCandidatesFilePath();
            MultipleInputs.addInputPath(job, new Path(filePath), inputFormatClass, GenericMapper.class);
            // SOMEHOW SEND KEY HERE
        }
    return true;
    }
```

The reason for doing this is to make this Job config driven. We will allow users of this job to upload very simple configurations via UI when they have to add new files to be taken into account. This will free us from making code changes and deployments whenever we have new use cases.

Comment: Can you add the key per row in your file and load all the rules in mapper? It will increase the file size but will do the trick

Comment: Thank you. Yes that is an option. But I was hoping to keep the files clean since it comes from elsewhere and just setup 'n' mappers dynamically based on the configuration. I ended up getting the filename as given in answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28056289/passing-different-parameters-to-each-mapper and then using it to get the key.